# PHP array_push in associative array

Tags: php

I am attempting to push a list of strings into a PHP associative array. Ideally, my data structure looks like the following:

```
$foo = array("key" -> array())
```

So what I'm trying to do is loop and do something like the following:

```
while loop 
 array_push($foo["key"], some_val);
done loop
```

This isn't building the array though as I anticipated it to do. What's missing here?

Comment: why not just do `$foo['key'][]` ?

Comment: What do you expect the result of the above code to be? No one can tell you what's missing if you don't tell us what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
function array_push_assoc($array, $key, $value){
    $array[$key] = $value;
    return $array;
}

$array = array_push_assoc($array, 'key', 'value');
```

You also can simply do this:

```
$array["key"] = $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use array_push here if you are in a loop anyway.

```
foreach($newStuff as $key=>$value){ $foo[$key] = $value; }
```

If you're outside of a loop and you want to insert multiple items simultaneously then use array_push.

Answer (score -1):

Simply do this :

```
While(COND){
 $foo["key"] = $some_val;
}
var_dump($foo);
```